# Inference justification labels for sequent calculus proofs in bussproofs

Tags: bussproofs

I'm working through Computability and Logic and need to construct proofs the same way they do in the book. However, I can't find anything about how to give inference justifications that are on the same lines as premises in the sequent-style proof. What I can do is this :

[image: Notice there are no justifications for the inferences]

But what I need to do is this: [image: Notice the justification rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you want.  How about

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \{A\}        & \implies \{A\} \tag{R0}        \\
  \{A,{\sim}A\} & \implies \varnothing \tag{R2a} \\
  \Gamma       & \implies \varnothing \tag{R1}.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but it should be `{\sim}A` to avoid an unwanted space.

Comment: Changed the answer as you suggested @egreg

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `bussproofs` in your question now, perhaps you want to use a proofs package, and I think the `prooftrees`package does what you want except the nice alignment of the implications.  But the package is suitable to write proofs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\forestset{line numbering=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    to prove={}
  }
  [
      \{ A \} \Rightarrow \{ A \}, just=(R0)
      [
          {\{A, \neg A\} \Rightarrow \varnothing}, just=(R2a)
          [
             \Gamma   \Rightarrow \varnothing, just=(R1)
             ]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image]